# curve_fit() got multiple values for argument 'p0' - What does this mean for the curve fit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

So, I wrote this script to interpret and graph data from a dynamic light scattering experiment. However, when I run the program I get this curvefit error for `p0`. Does any one have any idea what the problem could be? I've tried various things without any success. I need all values, so it doesn't really make much sense. Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def exp_fun(x, A, tau,beta):
    res = A * np.exp(-(x / tau) ** beta)
    return res


def exp_fun2(x, A, tau, tau2):
    res = (1-A) * np.exp(-(x / tau)) + ( A) * np.exp(-(x / tau2))
    return res

def exp_fun3(x, A1, tau, tau2, tau3,A2):
    res = (1 - A1-A2) * np.exp(-(x / tau)) + (A1) * np.exp(-(x / tau2))+ (A2) * np.exp(-(x / tau3))
    return res


def exp_fun2_str1(x, A, tau, tau2, beta):
    res = (1-A) * np.exp(-(x / tau)) + ( A) * np.exp(-(x / tau2) ** beta)
    return res


def exp_fun2_str2(x, A, tau, tau2, beta, beta2):
    res =  (1-A)*np.exp(-(x / tau) ** beta) + ( A) * np.exp(-(x / tau2) ** beta2)
    return res



filepath = "C:\\ref-bsa-10\\"
filename = 'BSA1000'
filenamestatic='bsa10table.txt'
numfiles = 24




# load the static data

static = np.loadtxt(filepath + filenamestatic , skiprows=1, usecols=[0, 1,8])

#following code changed due to unicode errors: probably because of text files
#static = pd.read_csv(filepath + filenamestatic , delimiter='\t',skiprows=1)
#staticdata= np.array(static.values)

#angles=staticdata[:,0]
q=np.sqrt(static[:,1])*10**-6
#load and analyse dynamics data


tau1 = np.zeros([numfiles])
tau2 = np.zeros([numfiles])
A = np.zeros([numfiles])
beta1 = np.zeros([numfiles])
beta2 = np.zeros([numfiles])

dbeta1 = np.zeros([numfiles])
dbeta2 = np.zeros([numfiles])
dtau2 = np.zeros([numfiles])
dtau1 = np.zeros([numfiles])
dA = np.zeros([numfiles])

colore = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, numfiles))
plt.figure()
ave_n=5
for i in range(numfiles):
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath + filename + "{:02d}_averaged_corr.txt".format(i), delimiter='\t', skiprows=2)
    print(data)
    a = np.array(data.values)
    g2=a[:, 1] / np.mean(a[1:10, 1])
    dg2=a[:, 2] / np.mean(a[1:10, 1])
    t=a[:, 0]
    plt.errorbar(t, g2, dg2, color=colore[i])

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_fun, t, g2, dg2,
#                                   A         tau      beta
                           bounds=([0.9,       0,       0, ],
                                   [1.1,    10 ** 9,    2, ]),
                           p0    =([1,        100,      1, ])  )


    plt.plot(t, exp_fun(t, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]), color='red',
             linestyle='dashed')

    A[i] = popt[0]
    dA[i] = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[0]

    tau1[i] = popt[1]
    dtau1[i] = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[1]

#    tau2[i] = popt[2]
#    dtau2[i] = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[2]

    beta1[i] = popt[2]
    dbeta1[i] = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[2]

#    beta2[i] = popt[4]
#    dbeta2[i] = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[4]

plt.xlabel('$t$ (ms)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel(r'$g_2$-1')
plt.grid('on')

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(q,A, dA,marker='o',linestyle='none')
plt.xlabel('q ($\mathrm{\mu}$m$^{-1}$)')
plt.ylabel('A')
plt.grid('on')

#plt.figure()
#plt.errorbar(q**4,1/tau2, 1/(tau2**2)*dtau2,marker='o',linestyle='none')
#plt.xlabel('q$^4$ ($\mathrm{\mu}$m$^{-4}$)')
#plt.ylabel('$\Gamma_2$ (s$^{-1}$)')
#plt.grid('on')



plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(q**2,1/tau1, 1/(tau1**2)*dtau1,marker='o',linestyle='none')

poptDp, pcovDp = curve_fit(lambda x, *p: x * p[0], q ** 2,1/tau1, p0=[1, 0], bounds=(0, 1000),
                           sigma=1/(tau1**2)*dtau1, ftol=1e-14, xtol=1e-14)  # old: 1e-15

plt.plot(q** 2 , q** 2  * poptDp[0] , color='magenta')
D=poptDp[0]
dD= np.sqrt(np.diag(pcovDp))[0]
plt.xlabel('q$^2$ ($\mathrm{\mu}$m$^{-2}$)')
plt.ylabel('$\Gamma_1$ (s$^{-1}$)')
plt.grid('on')


R=10*10**-9
Dms=D*10**3*(10**-6)**2
kb=1.380649*10**(-23)
eta=kb *(273.15+21)/(6*np.pi*R*Dms)


#comparing two functions
#plt.figure()
#plt.errorbar(q,1/tau2, 1/(tau2**2)*dtau2,marker='o',linestyle='none')
#plt.errorbar(q,1/tau1, 1/(tau1**2)*dtau1,marker='o',linestyle='none')
#plt.xlabel('q ($\mathrm{\mu}$m$^{-1}$)')
#plt.ylabel('$\Gamma$ (s$^{-1}$)')
#plt.grid('on')
#plt.xscale('log')
#plt.yscale('log')



plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(q,beta1, dbeta1,marker='o',linestyle='none')
#plt.errorbar(q,beta2, dbeta2,marker='o',linestyle='none')
plt.grid('on')

plt.xlabel('q ($\mathrm{\mu}$m$^{-1}$)')
plt.ylabel('KWW')
```

Comment: `p0    =([1,        100,      1, ])` seems odd. You have a list within a tuple, instead of just `p0    =(1,        100,      1, )`.

Comment: i tried changin that, but the same error popped up.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).